# AdonisJs Ace - E_IOC_LOOKUP_FAILED

Tags: node.js, adonis.js, adonisjs-ace

I'm trying to load the Event system into an ace command.

```
public async run() {
    const { default: Event } = await import('@ioc:Adonis/Core/Event')
}
```

However this results in the following error: `Cannot resolve "Adonis/Core/Event" namespace from the IoC Container`

Based on the documentation I'm doing this right: https://docs.adonisjs.com/guides/ace-commandline#top-level-imports-are-not-allowed

Could anyone please advise?

Answer (score 4):

Set `loadApp` in your command settings property to `true`.

Then, run the command `node ace generate:manifest`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this commandit solve your issue.

```
node ace generate:manifest
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally, This kind of issue occurs because people forget to add providers in .adonisrc.json

So, Please add the following this might be different for others' case

```
"providers": [
   "./providers/AppProvider",
   "@adonisjs/core",
   "@adonisjs/lucid",
   "@adonisjs/auth"
]
```